# Is it possible to make array empty without activating its DidSet property?

Tags: arrays, swift, didset

Currently I have an array that activates another function when set:

```
   var updatedBeaconDetailsArray = [BeaconDataDetails]() { didSet {
        self.updateBeaconData(beacon: self.updatedBeaconDetailsArray)
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to clear the array with activating the didSet since the didSet function is also tied to other parts of the app causing odd behavior.

So far I've tried:

```
self.updatedBeaconDetailsArray = []
self.updatedBeaconDetailsArray.removeAll()
```

but they all still activate the didSet, any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you checked to see if the array is empty inside of the didSet?
Something like:

```
var updatedBeaconDetailsArray = [BeaconDataDetails]() {
    didSet {
        if !updatedBeaconDetailsArray.isEmpty {
            self.updateBeaconData(beacon: self.updatedBeaconDetailsArray)
        }
    }
}
```